# How to run commands on remote machine using bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, centos6

I am trying to run the below commands on remote machine, but nothing is being getting executed, Can anyone point out the issue with the below script?

FYI settings.yml and fuscation_util.rb files are present in the `testuser` account

**SCRIPT:**

```
sshpass -p "PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T root@HOSTNAME <<EOF
    su - testuser
    NEWLINE=$'\n'
    read -s -p "Enter Presto Password:${NEWLINE}" VD_PASSWORD
    KEY=`cat settings.yml |grep '^key:'|sed 's/^key: //'`
    VALUE=`ruby fuscation_util.rb encrypt  "$KEY" "$VD_PASSWORD"`
    echo "$VALUE"
EOF
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
cat: settings.yml: No such file or directory
ruby: No such file or directory -- fuscation_util.rb (LoadError)
```

I am facing the error only when I try to assign the poutput to some variable, with the below script I didnt get any errors

**SCRIPT:**

```
sshpass -p "PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T root@HOSTNAME <<EOF
    su - testuser
    NEWLINE=$'\n'
    read -s -p "Enter Presto Password:${NEWLINE}" VD_PASSWORD
    cat settings.yml |grep '^key:'|sed 's/^key: //'
    ruby fuscation_util.rb encrypt  "testvalue" "testpassword"
EOF
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
WORKING FINE
```

Comment: Try adding the exact path to file w.r.t `root` user.

Comment: @Shravan40 - that's a good suggestion - mind if I add that as a 2nd option to my answer?

Comment: @Lix : Please add.

Comment: I would like to point out few things that you can change/improve. 1. I dont see any point in doing `read` and getting `VD_PASSWORD` from inside the ssh script. You can rather do it from outside and pass it in. 2. As suggested by others use absolute path for settings.yml and fuscation_util.rb

Comment: cat: /opt/settings.yml: No such file or directory
ruby: No such file or directory -- /opt/fuscation_util.rb (LoadError)

Getting same error with absolute path also

Answer (score 0):

I believe that because you are connecting as root, the directory you land in when connecting is the root user home directory. Even though you change users, you would still be in the same starting folder (probably `/root`).

If you explicitly `cd` into the desired location before executing the commands, you'll have access to the desired files.

Another option ([suggested by Shravan40](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38099465/how-to-run-commands-on-remote-machine-using-bash-script#comment63633254_38099465)) would be to specify absolute paths to the files you wish to handle.

---

It should be mentioned also that allowing root access via SSH is considered a security risk. I would suggest avoiding that if at all possible.

Comment: cat: /opt/settings.yml: No such file or directory
ruby: No such file or directory -- /opt/fuscation_util.rb (LoadError)

Getting same error with absolute path also

Comment: You said "files are present in the testuser account" is the testuser account located in the /opt folder? Are you certain that the this is the correct path to the files?

Comment: Yes, we have given permission to testuser to access the opt dir, FYI our server architecture is totally different and all our servers are meant for internal use only

Comment: I don't mean permissions - the error states that the file can not be found. Are you sure that the desired files are in the /opt folder?

Comment: Files are present, I am getting the error only when I trry to assign the output to an variable, if I remove the assignment, then everything works without any issues

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your ssh connect to the remote host as root it goes to the root directory. So try a change directory inside or give absolute path to the files.

Buts its a security risk though to run commands remotely. Probably you can place a script on the remote host and pass parameter, rather using an echo inside ssh.

**Update:**

Just make all the assignments before the ssh and use key value as expressions while calling ruby.

**Try this:**

```
read -s -p "Enter Presto Password:${NEWLINE}" VD_PASSWORD
sshpass -p "PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T root@HOSTNAME <<EOF
su - testuser
cat settings.yml |grep '^key:'|sed 's/^key: //'
ruby fuscation_util.rb encrypt  `cat settings.yml|grep '^key:'|sed 's/^key: //'` $VD_PASSWORD
EOF
```

Comment: cat: /opt/settings.yml: No such file or directory
ruby: No such file or directory -- /opt/fuscation_util.rb (LoadError)

Getting same error with absolute path also

Comment: "/opt/settings.yml: no such file" because that command is executed at the local machine, not the remote server. To confirm that cd to a different directory like /tmp and see how /opt/settings.yml becomes /tmp/settings.yml.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using full path and those things you need to replace `<<EOF` with   `<<'EOF'` or all the back ticks will be processed on the calling side before they are sent over to remote side.

Comment: I tried it already, when i repalce with 'EOF', then the variable assignment is not working